# Tooltip on a silverlight component using html

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Is there any way one can get tooltip on a Silverlight Control just like an image has "Alt" text in ??

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, anything included via  or  is outside the control of the normal browser renderer. So the short answer is "no".

As a hack, you might be able to overlay a transparent element over the top of the object and assign a title attribute to that. I wouldn't go down that route though.

If you want a tooltip in an embeded object, then get the object to generate it itself.

As an aside - alt text does not display as a tooltip in most browsers. You should probably read [ALT texts in IMG](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html) so you can learn how to use them properly.